# UICollectionView very slow to load because of dequeueWithReusableIdentifier, can I load it in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm facing an issue I reaaaally don't find any answer to.
I have a collectionView, and every time I tap a button, I reloadData of the collectionView with new parameters. My problem is that it takes around 1-2s to do so wich is very annoying and freeze my UI.

I would like to know if there is a way to reload the collectionView in background and diplay it only when it's done, something like (in pseudo-code) :

```
self.collectionView.hidden = yes;
dispatch_async({
   [self.collectionView reloadData];
});
```

and when the it's fully updated :

```
self.collectionView.hidden = no;
```

I haven't found anything about how to this on the internet, and i really need some help.

Full code for cellForRowAtIndexPath method :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = nil;

    if (indexPath.row >= 1 && indexPath.row <= 7)
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"AGZDayLetterCell";
        cell =(AGZDayLetterCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        ((AGZDayLetterCollectionViewCell*)cell).dayFirstLetterLabel.text = [self.daysFirstLetterArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1)];
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row%8 == 0)
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"AGZSeparatorCell";
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row > 8+self.delay)
    {
        NSString *dayNumberTapped = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row-7-(int)indexPath.row/8-self.delay];

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"AGZDayCell";
        cell =(AGZDayCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        ((AGZDayCollectionViewCell*)cell).dateTappedString = [self getDateStringForDayNumber:dayNumberTapped];

        NSDate *selectedDayDate = [[self getDateStringForDayNumber:dayNumberTapped] dateFromStringForRFC3339Format];
        ((AGZDayCollectionViewCell*)cell).dayAppointmentsArray = (NSMutableArray*)[self.appointmentsDictionary objectForKey:[selectedDayDate getDateOnlyRFC3339Format]];

        // We check if the cell is today's date and set the design according to the result
        if ([[self.viewDate getDateOnly] isEqualToString:[[NSDate date] getDateOnly]] && [[NSDate date] getDay] == [dayNumberTapped intValue])
            ((AGZDayCollectionViewCell*)cell).isTodayDay = YES;
        else
            ((AGZDayCollectionViewCell*)cell).isTodayDay = NO;
    }
    else {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"AGZDayCell";
        cell =(AGZDayCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        ((AGZDayCollectionViewCell*)cell).dateTappedString = @"";
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        ((AGZDayCollectionViewCell*)cell).isTodayDay = NO;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: show your code in collectionView datasource plz

Comment: Is this code running on the main thread?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that should cause the slowness you're observing, so there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's very unlikely that the issue is the collection view. Many people are using them in all sorts of ways with far better performance than you are getting. What's more likely is that whatever code is generating the data is taking the time. For example - hitting a server. That's the code that should be on a back ground thread with a call back or completion block attached.

UI code should never be on a background three and will cause all sorts of UI issues if not run on the main thread.

Comment: I've run uicollectionview before, nothing is called from server while reloadingData, running the time instruments show that it's the dequeueReusableCell that takes a lot of time (more than 1s)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

This helped a lot me to improve performance in CollectionView,If you are loading images in your cells dynamically.